# Trouble compiling linux C program in cygwin

Tags: c, linux, audio, cygwin, pulseaudio

I'm trying to compile a program called minimodem for linux in Cygwin, because I want to be able to run it in windows. It's a simple command line program, and I installed Cygwin with basically all of the required libraries to compile it.

Some of the libraries are: All the audio, video, math, compile, develop, api, and system and base are installed.

One of the first problems I ran into was ./configure. From the source code of the project in github, there is no configure file or folder. I decided to ditch that and instead use make directly instead and reference all the files in the folder.

First what happened is I got this error:

> minimodem.c: In function ‘main’: minimodem.c:556:4: error: #error At
>   least one of {USE_PULSEAUDIO,USE_ALSA,USE_SNDFILE} must be enabled!  #
>   error At least one of {USE_PULSEAUDIO,USE_ALSA,USE_SNDFILE} must be
>   enabled!
>       ^~~~~

so I went into the code and removed the part that checks the audio driver(even though Cygwin has all the audio libraries available) and I tried it again:

> gcc -o minimodem.c

Then the compiler got a bit farther
and then gave this error:

```
/tmp/cc5sSG5R.o: In function `fsk_transmit_frame':
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:95: undefined reference to `simpleaudio_tone'
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:95:(.text+0xb9): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `simpleaudio_tone'
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:106: undefined reference to `simpleaudio_tone'
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:106:(.text+0xf2): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `simpleaudio_tone'
/tmp/cc5sSG5R.o: In function `tx_stop_transmit_sighandler':
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:65: undefined reference to `simpleaudio_tone'
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:65:(.text+0x27f): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `simpleaudio_tone'
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:68: undefined reference to `simpleaudio_tone'
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:68:(.text+0x2ec): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `simpleaudio_tone'
/tmp/cc5sSG5R.o: In function `generate_test_tones':
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:295: undefined reference to `simpleaudio_get_rate'
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:295:(.text+0x59d): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `simpleaudio_get_rate'
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:299: undefined reference to `simpleaudio_tone'
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:299:(.text+0x5dd): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `simpleaudio_tone'
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:300: undefined reference to `simpleaudio_tone'
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:300:(.text+0x5eb): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `simpleaudio_tone'
/tmp/cc5sSG5R.o: In function `fsk_transmit_frame':
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:109: undefined reference to `simpleaudio_tone'
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:109:(.text+0x170): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `simpleaudio_tone'
/tmp/cc5sSG5R.o: In function `main':
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:751: undefined reference to `databits_decode_ascii8'
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:751:(.text.startup+0xa6): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `databits_decode_ascii8'
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:751: undefined reference to `databits_encode_ascii8'
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:751:(.text.startup+0xc6): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `databits_encode_ascii8'
/tmp/cc5sSG5R.o: In function `benchmarks':
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:324: undefined reference to `simpleaudio_tone_init'
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:324:(.text.startup+0x2b3): additional relocation overflows omitted from the output
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:326: undefined reference to `simpleaudio_open_stream'
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:332: undefined reference to `simpleaudio_close'
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:334: undefined reference to `simpleaudio_open_stream'
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:340: undefined reference to `simpleaudio_close'
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:344: undefined reference to `simpleaudio_tone_init'
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:346: undefined reference to `simpleaudio_open_stream'
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:352: undefined reference to `simpleaudio_close'
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:354: undefined reference to `simpleaudio_open_stream'
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:360: undefined reference to `simpleaudio_close'
/tmp/cc5sSG5R.o: In function `main':
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:665: undefined reference to `databits_decode_baudot'
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:666: undefined reference to `baudot_encode'
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:797: undefined reference to `databits_decode_baudot'
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:798: undefined reference to `baudot_encode'
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:864: undefined reference to `databits_decode_binary'
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:945: undefined reference to `simpleaudio_tone_init'
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:954: undefined reference to `simpleaudio_open_stream'
/tmp/cc5sSG5R.o: In function `fsk_transmit_stdin':
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:130: undefined reference to `simpleaudio_get_rate'
/tmp/cc5sSG5R.o: In function `main':
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:975: undefined reference to `simpleaudio_close'
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:805: undefined reference to `databits_decode_baudot'
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:806: undefined reference to `baudot_encode'
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:988: undefined reference to `simpleaudio_open_stream'
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:995: undefined reference to `simpleaudio_get_rate'
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:1011: undefined reference to `fsk_plan_new'
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:1232: undefined reference to `fsk_find_frame'
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:1443: undefined reference to `simpleaudio_close'
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:1445: undefined reference to `fsk_plan_destroy'
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:833: undefined reference to `databits_decode_callerid'
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:998: undefined reference to `simpleaudio_set_rxnoise'
/tmp/cc5sSG5R.o: In function `fsk_transmit_stdin':
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:211: undefined reference to `simpleaudio_tone'
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:233: undefined reference to `simpleaudio_tone'
/tmp/cc5sSG5R.o: In function `main':
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:1132: undefined reference to `simpleaudio_read'
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:1340: undefined reference to `fsk_find_frame'
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:1155: undefined reference to `fsk_detect_carrier'
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:1186: undefined reference to `fsk_set_tones_by_bandshift'
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:845: undefined reference to `databits_decode_uic_ground'
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:833: undefined reference to `databits_decode_callerid'
/home/8bit_coder/minimodem-master/src/minimodem.c:843: undefined reference to `databits_decode_uic_train'
/tmp/cc5sSG5R.o:minimodem.c:(.rdata$.refptr.databits_decode_binary[.refptr.databits_decode_binary]+0x0): undefined reference to `databits_decode_binary'
/tmp/cc5sSG5R.o:minimodem.c:(.rdata$.refptr.databits_decode_uic_train[.refptr.databits_decode_uic_train]+0x0): undefined reference to `databits_decode_uic_train'
/tmp/cc5sSG5R.o:minimodem.c:(.rdata$.refptr.databits_decode_uic_ground[.refptr.databits_decode_uic_ground]+0x0): undefined reference to `databits_decode_uic_ground'
/tmp/cc5sSG5R.o:minimodem.c:(.rdata$.refptr.databits_decode_callerid[.refptr.databits_decode_callerid]+0x0): undefined reference to `databits_decode_callerid'
/tmp/cc5sSG5R.o:minimodem.c:(.rdata$.refptr.databits_encode_ascii8[.refptr.databits_encode_ascii8]+0x0): undefined reference to `databits_encode_ascii8'
/tmp/cc5sSG5R.o:minimodem.c:(.rdata$.refptr.databits_decode_ascii8[.refptr.databits_decode_ascii8]+0x0): undefined reference to `databits_decode_ascii8'
/tmp/cc5sSG5R.o:minimodem.c:(.rdata$.refptr.baudot_encode[.refptr.baudot_encode]+0x0): undefined reference to `baudot_encode'
/tmp/cc5sSG5R.o:minimodem.c:(.rdata$.refptr.databits_decode_baudot[.refptr.databits_decode_baudot]+0x0): undefined reference to `databits_decode_baudot'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Then I thought maybe I needed to list every file:

> gcc -o baudot.c baudot.h databits.h databits_ascii.c databits_baudot.c
>   databits_binary.c databits_callerid.c databits_uic.c fsk.c fsk.h
>   minimodem.c simpleaudio.c simpleaudio.h simpleaudio_internal.h
>   simpleaudio-alsa.c simpleaudio-benchmark.c simpleaudio-pulse.c
>   simpleaudio-sndfile.c simple-tone-generator.c uic_codes.c uic_codes.h

But that gave a load of different errors:

```
/tmp/ccmwpyzy.o:databits_baudot.c:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `baudot_reset'
/tmp/ccmwpyzy.o:databits_baudot.c:(.text+0x1f): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `baudot_reset'
/tmp/ccmwpyzy.o:databits_baudot.c:(.text+0x3d): undefined reference to `baudot_decode'
/tmp/ccmwpyzy.o:databits_baudot.c:(.text+0x3d): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `baudot_decode'
/tmp/cc6Uh66Z.o:fsk.c:(.text+0x1b8): undefined reference to `fftwf_malloc'
/tmp/cc6Uh66Z.o:fsk.c:(.text+0x1b8): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `fftwf_malloc'
/tmp/cc6Uh66Z.o:fsk.c:(.text+0x208): undefined reference to `fftwf_malloc'
/tmp/cc6Uh66Z.o:fsk.c:(.text+0x208): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `fftwf_malloc'
/tmp/cc6Uh66Z.o:fsk.c:(.text+0x281): undefined reference to `fftwf_plan_many_dft_r2c'
/tmp/cc6Uh66Z.o:fsk.c:(.text+0x281): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `fftwf_plan_many_dft_r2c'
/tmp/cc6Uh66Z.o:fsk.c:(.text+0x2cc): undefined reference to `fftwf_free'
/tmp/cc6Uh66Z.o:fsk.c:(.text+0x2cc): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `fftwf_free'
/tmp/cc6Uh66Z.o:fsk.c:(.text+0x2dc): undefined reference to `fftwf_free'
/tmp/cc6Uh66Z.o:fsk.c:(.text+0x2dc): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `fftwf_free'
/tmp/cc6Uh66Z.o:fsk.c:(.text+0x323): undefined reference to `fftwf_free'
/tmp/cc6Uh66Z.o:fsk.c:(.text+0x323): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `fftwf_free'
/tmp/cc6Uh66Z.o:fsk.c:(.text+0x333): undefined reference to `fftwf_free'
/tmp/cc6Uh66Z.o:fsk.c:(.text+0x333): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `fftwf_free'
/tmp/cc6Uh66Z.o:fsk.c:(.text+0x343): undefined reference to `fftwf_destroy_plan'
/tmp/cc6Uh66Z.o:fsk.c:(.text+0x343): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `fftwf_destroy_plan'
/tmp/cc6Uh66Z.o:fsk.c:(.text+0x454): undefined reference to `fftwf_execute'
/tmp/cc6Uh66Z.o:fsk.c:(.text+0x454): additional relocation overflows omitted from the output
/tmp/cc6Uh66Z.o:fsk.c:(.text+0xda7): undefined reference to `fftwf_execute'
/tmp/ccmR4Dzs.o:minimodem.c:(.rdata$.refptr.baudot_encode[.refptr.baudot_encode]+0x0): undefined reference to `baudot_encode'
/tmp/ccBHdt9j.o:simpleaudio.c:(.rdata$.refptr.simpleaudio_backend_alsa[.refptr.simpleaudio_backend_alsa]+0x0): undefined reference to `simpleaudio_backend_alsa'
/tmp/ccBHdt9j.o:simpleaudio.c:(.rdata$.refptr.simpleaudio_backend_pulseaudio[.refptr.simpleaudio_backend_pulseaudio]+0x0): undefined reference to `simpleaudio_backend_pulseaudio'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

At this point I don't know what to do since it compiles fine and runs on Linux but using Cygwin to compile it on windows does that. If anyone has any idea about  what I'm doing wrong or how I can fix the command or files so that it works, thanks.

Comment: Not all code can be compiled on different systems. If the code requires a specific audio system, it might not be available.

Comment: @8bit_coder you show the error but not the compiler command. You are also missing the fftw3-devel package for `fftwf_malloc` and company

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by @Sami Kuhmonen in a comment to your question:

> Not all code can be compiled on different systems. If the code
>   requires a specific audio system, it might not be available

In this case the three libraries it tries to use but fails at:

- [PulseAudio](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/?) : A sound system for POSIX OSs (not windows, however : has been tested on Windows 2000 and Windows XP) So windows support would be very limited at best in my opinion
- [ALSA](https://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Main_Page) : It states in its name Advanced Linux Sound Architecture (probably not windows right?) This is Linux specific code for communicating with sound card drivers on Linux platforms.
- [libsndfile](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/) : It says on the website it has pre-compiled binaries for Win32 and Win64 OSs, but it doesn't look like originally it was designed with windows in mind

All in all, audio code like this is probably trying to communicate with specific drivers designed only for a Linux based system ([Linux vs Windows Audio in 2017](https://www.learndigitalaudio.com/how-linux-audio-works-vs-windows-audio-2017)). And although C can be portable across different OSs, the code written here in the libraries you are compiling your program with, is most likely not.

I'm pretty sure you would have to edit (port) the source code to work with more relavant windows audio programming in mind.

**Note:**

Thanks to the comment from @matzeri, there's actually a `libsndfile` package on Cygwin. See the [link here](https://cygwin.com/packages/x86_64/libsndfile/).

Comment: `libsndfile` is available on cygwin https://cygwin.com/packages/x86_64/libsndfile/